# How to use tabula in AWS Lambda to read PDF table

Tags: python, aws-lambda, tabula-py

Hello I get the following error while trying to use tabula to read a table in a pdf.

I was aware of some of the difficulties ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60391781/aws-lambda-oserror30-read-only-file-system)) using this package with AWS lambda and tried to zip the tabula package via an EC2 (Ubuntu 20.02) and then, add it as a layer in the function.

Many thanks in advance!

`` { "errorMessage": "`java` command is not found from this Python process.Please ensure Java is installed and PATH is set for `java`", "errorType": "JavaNotFoundError", "stackTrace": [ "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 39, in lambda_handler\n    df = tabula.read_pdf(BytesIO(fs), pages=\"all\", area = [box],\n", "  File \"/opt/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tabula/io.py\", line 420, in read_pdf\n    output = _run(java_options, tabula_options, path, encoding)\n", "  File \"/opt/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tabula/io.py\", line 98, in _run\n    raise JavaNotFoundError(JAVA_NOT_FOUND_ERROR)\n" ] } ``

**Code**

```
import boto3

import read_pdf from tabula
from io import BytesIO

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    client = boto3.client('s3')
    
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

    # Get most recent file name
    response = client.list_objects_v2(Bucket='S3bucket')
    all = response['Contents']        
    latest = max(all, key=lambda x: x['LastModified'])
    latest_key = latest['Key'] 
    
    # Get file
    obj = s3.Object('S3bucket', latest_key)
    fs = obj.get()['Body'].read()
    
    # Read PDF
    box = [3.99, .22, 8.3, 7.86]
    fc = 72
             
    for i in range(0, len(box)):
        box[i] *= fc
        
    df = tabula.read_pdf(BytesIO(fs), pages="all", area = [box], output_format = "dataframe", lattice=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the Dockerfile that ultimatley worked and allowed me to run tabula in my lambda function:

```
ARG FUNCTION_DIR="/var/task/"

COPY ./ ${FUNCTION_DIR}

# Install OpenJDK
RUN yum install -y java-1.8.0-openjdk


# Setup Python environment
# Install PYTHON requirements
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Copy function code to container
COPY app.py ./


CMD [ "app.handler" ]
```

Comment: I put together a more detailed answer that uses this approach here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76516017/how-to-use-tabula-on-aws-lambda-to-read-pdf

Answer (score 0):

Tabula's python package is just a wrapper for java code.  Here's a reference to the package [here](https://pypi.org/project/tabula-py/).

Java 8+ is required to be installed for this to work.  Your best bet to achieve that is to develop a docker container image where your script works and deploy that image as a lambda function.

AWS has a good [walkthrough](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/patterns/deploy-lambda-functions-with-container-images.html) that might help.