# How to use tabula on AWS Lambda to read pdf?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, tabula, tabula-py

`I know that we have to download Java for it to run, I did it on my IDE and it worked. But idk how to download it on the AWS Lambda. If anyone could help me with that I would appreciate it.

I Think the code itself produces what I am expecting, however, the java is what I need.

This is the error I am getting :

`

`'[ERROR] JavaNotFoundError:` java`command is not found from this Python process.Please ensure Java is installed and PATH is set for`java`Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 30, in lambda_handler     tables = tabula.read_pdf(io.BytesIO(file_content), pages='all')   File "/opt/python/tabula/io.py", line 425, in read_pdf     output = _run(java_options, tabula_options, path, encoding)   File "/opt/python/tabula/io.py", line 99, in _run     raise JavaNotFoundError(JAVA_NOT_FOUND_ERROR)'`

```
            import json
            import boto3
            import pandas as pd
            import io
            import re
            import tabula
            import numpy as np
            def f_remove_accents(old):
                """
            #    Removes common accent characters, lower form.
            #    Uses: regex.
                """
                new = old.lower()
                new = re.sub(r'[àáâãäå]', 'a', new)
                new = re.sub(r'[èéêë]', 'e', new)
                new = re.sub(r'[ìíîï]', 'i', new)
                new = re.sub(r'[òóôõö]', 'o', new)
                new = re.sub(r'[ùúûü]', 'u', new)
                new = re.sub(r'[ç]', 'c', new)
                return new
            def lambda_handler(event, context):
                s3 = boto3.client("s3")
                if event:
                    s3_records = event["Records"][0]
                    bucket_name = str(s3_records["s3"]["bucket"]["name"])
                    file_name = str(s3_records["s3"]["object"]["key"])
                    file_obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=file_name)
                    file_content = file_obj["Body"].read()
            
                    tables = tabula.read_pdf(io.BytesIO(file_content), pages='all')
            
            
                    # Create an empty DataFrame to store all the modified tables
                    modified_tables = []
            
                    # Apply functions to the content of each table
                    for table in tables:
                        # Convert the DataFrame to a NumPy array
                        table_array = table.values.astype(str)
            
                        # Remove accents
                        remove_accents_func = np.vectorize(f_remove_accents)
                        table_array = remove_accents_func(table_array)
            
                        # Replace ';' with ' '
                        table_array = np.char.replace(table_array, ';', ' ')
            
                        # Convert to upper case
                        table_array = np.char.upper(table_array)
            
                        # Create a new DataFrame with the modified array
                        modified_table = pd.DataFrame(table_array, columns=table.columns)
            
                        # Append the modified table to the list
                        modified_tables.append(modified_table)
            
                    # Concatenate all the modified tables into a single DataFrame
                    final_df = pd.concat(modified_tables, ignore_index=True)
            
                    # Save the final DataFrame as a CSV file
                    name_of_return_file = f'{file_name[:-4]}_return.csv'
                    final_df.to_csv(name_of_return_file, sep=';', index=False)
            
                    # Read the CSV file content
                    with open(name_of_return_file, 'rb') as file:
                        csv_content = file.read()
            
                    # Upload the CSV file to the destination bucket
                    s3.put_object(Body=csv_content, Bucket='bucket-recebendo', Key=name_of_return_file)
```

Comment: Have you looked at this previous answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73807086/how-to-use-tabula-in-aws-lambda-to-read-pdf-table - it looks like you might need to create an OCI image

Comment: Yes I saw it, but wasn't able to apply it to mine

Comment: I’ve added a solution that works for me

Answer (score 1):

So this is how I managed to get tabular up and running on Lambda. I used the OCI capability of Lambda to package up the requirements.

First of all, I used VSCode to create my folder structure that to put my lambda function and Docker file.

I created a file called "lambda_function.py" that had the code you listed above. I created a pip requirements.txt file that had the following libraries (you should not use this but use pinned versions, I am only doing this for speed)

I did have to change your code, and I made the following changes (import statements)

```
import json
import boto3
import pandas as pd
import io
import re
from tabula.io import read_pdf
import numpy as np
..
..
```

as I was getting errors with "AttributeError: module 'tabula' has no attribute 'read_pdf'"

```
pandas
numpy
tabula-py
boto3
```

Then I created my Docker file (very rough, not optimised but just to bootstrap this and get it going - you defo want to improve this)

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.10
COPY requirements.txt ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
COPY lambda_function.py ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
RUN yum install java-17-amazon-corretto-devel -y
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
CMD [ "lambda_function.lambda_handler" ]
```

This is what my layout looked like:

```
├── Dockerfile
├── lambda_function.py
└── requirements.txt
```

I then ran the following commands to build my container image locally and then upload it to amazon ecr (I had created an ecr repo)

```
docker build -t lambda-tabula:1.0.0 . 
aws ecr get-login-password --region eu-west-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin xxxx.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
docker tag lambda-tabula:1.0.0 xxxx.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/lambda-oci-demo:1.0.1
docker push xxxx.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/lambda-oci-demo:1.0.1
```

I now had my image in ECR, which I could reference via an arn ("xxxxx.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/lambda-oci-demo:1.0.0")

I then created a new Lambda function, specifying OCI image and then pointing to this image. I created a role for the function that would provide permissions to this specific S3 bucket too.

You can grab more details in the [docs here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-image.html)

This allows the function to run, although it fails with a different error due to the current function wanting to write to a read only filesystem, so I changed name_of_return_file = f'{file_name[:-4]}_return.csv' to be name_of_return_file = f'/tmp/{file_name[:-4]}_return.csv'

Once I fixed that, it worked great. Here is the updated code

```
import json
import boto3
import pandas as pd
import io
import re
from tabula.io import read_pdf
import numpy as np
def f_remove_accents(old):
            new = old.lower()
            new = re.sub(r'[àáâãäå]', 'a', new)
            new = re.sub(r'[èéêë]', 'e', new)
            new = re.sub(r'[ìíîï]', 'i', new)
            new = re.sub(r'[òóôõö]', 'o', new)
            new = re.sub(r'[ùúûü]', 'u', new)
            new = re.sub(r'[ç]', 'c', new)
            return new
def lambda_handler(event, context):
            s3 = boto3.client("s3")
            if event:
                    #s3_records = event["Records"][0]
                    #bucket_name = str(s3_records["s3"]["bucket"]["name"])
                    #file_name = str(s3_records["s3"]["object"]["key"])
                    #file_obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=file_name)
                    file_obj = s3.get_object(Bucket="tabula-demo", Key="invoice.pdf")
                    file_content = file_obj["Body"].read()
            
                    tables = read_pdf(io.BytesIO(file_content), pages='all')
            
            
                    # Create an empty DataFrame to store all the modified tables
                    modified_tables = []
            
                    # Apply functions to the content of each table
                    for table in tables:
                        # Convert the DataFrame to a NumPy array
                        table_array = table.values.astype(str)
            
                        # Remove accents
                        remove_accents_func = np.vectorize(f_remove_accents)
                        table_array = remove_accents_func(table_array)
            
                        # Replace ';' with ' '
                        table_array = np.char.replace(table_array, ';', ' ')
            
                        # Convert to upper case
                        table_array = np.char.upper(table_array)
            
                        # Create a new DataFrame with the modified array
                        modified_table = pd.DataFrame(table_array, columns=table.columns)
            
                        # Append the modified table to the list
                        modified_tables.append(modified_table)
            
                    # Concatenate all the modified tables into a single DataFrame
                    final_df = pd.concat(modified_tables, ignore_index=True)
            
                    # Save the final DataFrame as a CSV file
                    #name_of_return_file = f'{file_name[:-4]}_return.csv'
                    name_of_return_file = '/tmp/test_return.csv'
                    final_df.to_csv(name_of_return_file, sep=';', index=False)
            
                    # Read the CSV file content
                    with open(name_of_return_file, 'rb') as file:
                        csv_content = file.read()
            
                    # Upload the CSV file to the destination bucket
                    s3.put_object(Body=csv_content, Bucket='094459-lambda-libs', Key=name_of_return_file)
```

Note! I had to modify the code above as I hard coded a file as I didnt know what your input files were.

Comment: I tried a simple invoice pdf when trying this out, and the output generated was pretty decent.